# Print Composer Atlas multiple feature select in one page

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, atlas

I am trying to select multiple features on Print Composer in QGIS 2.18 (Las Palmas) in the atlas filter: for instance, I have one layer whose atributte `"name"=2` has 4 features as a result; the resulting atlas shows me 4 pages (one page per feature).
But I want to show these 4 features highlighted just in one page. Is it possible?

Comment: The behaviour u expect is not the behaviour of the atlas (one page per feature). In your case can't u select your 4 features, zoom to those 4 selected features and print your composer at this scale ? You can also apply a given style in order to hide unselected features.

Comment: @snaileater thanks for answering.
I finally made a postgis view which returns all the elements to me as if it were one.

Comment: @snaileater I can not use that solution because I do not select the objects without using the atlas in the print composer